# Running promises in parallel with Angular 1.x without stop on fail

Tags: angularjs

I am fetching some images using `$http.get()`. I am calling them currently using `$q.all()` however if one call/promise fails they all do. Is there another way I could do this?

```
$q.all([$http.get('..'),$http.get('..')]).then(function(res) {
  // this will never happen if one get fails.
}
```

Comment: You could wrap each get with a promise so that when the get is done (fail or success), it will resolve its individual promise.

Comment: Never heard of `$q.map()`. Show some relevant code. No reason individual requests need to all fail ... only the final `when()` but even that can be circumvented with individual `catch`

Comment: @BryanEuton - $http.get already returns a promise.

Comment: @charlietfl Typo. I meant $q.all()

Comment: Figured that was it. Can still make it work by returning from `catch` of individual request promises

Comment: I know get is already in a promise.  But if you wrap it in a promise that always resolve success regardless of the GET's outcome, then your problem would be fixed if I understood it correctly.

Comment: Ah yes. Got it. I think you are both suggesting the same approach. I will give this a shot

Comment: @BryanEuton simpler than that...see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple proof of concept using `catch()`

```
var req1 =  $http.get('..').catch(function(err){ return err; });
var req2 =  $http.get('..').catch(function(err){ return err; });

$q.all([req1,req2]).then(function(results) {
     var counts = {pass:0, fail:0}
     results.forEach(function(item){
       var type = item.status === 200 ? 'pass':'fail';
       counts[type]++;
     });
     alert('Results status =' + JSON.stringify(counts))
});
```

Because you return something from catch it resolves the initial promise and passes that return down the promise chain (to results array in this case) .

The success callback of `$q.all().then` will fire as a result

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/DMMSaza3HMKpPBE6ZCIh?p=preview)**</kbd>